# Is "for sure" an adverbial phrase?

Tags: adverbials

"Of course" is regarded as an adverbial phrase, even though the components of it appear to be a preposition and a noun.

So what about the phrase "for sure" (when used to mean for certain or certainly). First, is the phrase also an adverbial phrase and, if not, what is it. Second, what are the component parts? They appear to be a preposition and either an adjective or adverb.

Comment: Please can you give an example sentence?

Comment: If you can replace it with *certainly* with no change in meaning ...

Comment: One thing's for sure, it's not totally interchangeable with 'certainly'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's for sure.

Answer (score 3):

## Summary

1. The prepositional phrase *for sure* comprises the preposition *for* and its complement *sure*, which is an adjective. It remains a prepositional phrase no matter what use you put it to.
2. It is **not possible** to categorically state that the prepositional phrase *for sure* is always acting adverbially because that assessment can be made only within a surrounding syntactic context. Sometimes it is an adverbial modifier phrase and sometimes it is an adjectival modifier phrase. You can determine which applies by swapping it for a single-word adjective or a single-word adverb.

---

#### *Inside the phrase*

In the two-word phrase *for sure*, the word *for* is a preposition and the word *sure* is its complement, even though it is an adjective not a noun. (An argument that it is a conjunction here not a preposition is possible, but I shall not be making it.)

Specifically, this is the sense of *for* that means *as* or *as being*. Notice that *as being* lends itself to accepting complements that are equally likely to be nouns or adjectives.

The OED explains in sense **19b** below:

> ## for, *prep*. and *conj*.
>
> ### A. *prep.*
>
> #### VI. Of attributed or assumed character; = as.
>
> 19. **a.** In the character of, in the light of, as equivalent to; esp. to
>     introduce the complement after verbs of incomplete predication, e.g. *to
>     have, hold,* etc. (see those verbs), where *as* or *as being* may generally
>     be substituted. *to beg (a person) for a fool*: see **beg** *v.* 5a. 
>     **b.** So with an adjective, as in ***to take for granted, to leave for
>     dead,*** etc. ***for certain, for sure***, †***for wiss***, see those adjectives.
>     Also, with mixture of sense A. 8, as in the formula of the Marriage
>     Service (quot. 1549) where the sense is ‘whether she prove better or
>     worse’, etc.

And under **sure** *adj.* they give this sense for that phrase down in the phrases section:

> ## sure, *adj*., *adv*., and *int*.
>
> ### Phrases
>
> **P4.** ***for sure***: as a certainty, for certain; without doubt; undoubtedly. Frequently in ***that’s for sure***. In later, colloquial use often used emphatically at the end of a sentence.

#### *Outside the phrase*

As syntactic constituents, prepositional phrases are always modifier phrases; they are neither noun phrases nor verb phrases. Your phrase *for sure* is no different than any other prepositional phrase in this regard. That means you can exchange it for any other syntactic constituent acting in a modifier role.

Consider this citation, a fairly typical use:

> - **1971**   C. Bonington *Annapurna South Face* xiii. 156  
>    We can’t do it in the next two days..—that’s for sure.

Here *for sure* is acting as a predicate complement to *that is*. If you swapped it for the adjective *certain*, it would be perfectly grammatical and indeed mean the very same thing. Because that would be a predicate adjective, that means here your prepositional phrase is acting as an adjectival modifier phrase, not as an adverbial one.

But consider how it is used in this earlier but better known citation:

> - **1883**   Robert Louis Stevenson *Treasure Island* ɪ. vi. 52 
>     These fellows who attacked the inn tonight—bold, desperate blades, for sure.

Here I would not attempt to make the case that your prepositional phrase is being used adjectivally. Notice that you could exchange it for either of *surely* or *certainly*, both adverbs, which no change in grammar or indeed meaning. That makes it an adverbial modifier — although I leave it to others to decide whether it’s acting on the adjectives *bold, desperate*, or whether it’s actually a sentence adverbial against an entire copular  clause whose verb has now gone missing (*surely* is well known for being able to be a sentence adverb).

There’s one other case to look at, though. Instead of predicative uses, it can also be used attributively. Here are several illustrations from Google Books:

> 1. With the microchip, it is not a for sure bet, but your odds are much higher of getting your lost dog back, then [*sic*] if you did not have it.
> 2. Pick a date of the month and make it a “for sure” time to get together and discuss money.
> 3. It looked like a dragon, kind of, but it wasn't a “for sure” sort of thing. What was for sure was that it was adorable.
> 4. This is accomplished by not giving a "for sure" option at all (Table 5, Situation 2). If the subject is not indifferent to the two options in Situation 2, adjustment is allowed in order to guard against the "for sure" bias.

Those attributive uses just given are all clearly adjectival ones because you can exchange them for the adjective *certain* without affecting the grammar at all, nor even the meaning.

Comment: Yes, I should have probably provided it in context, but your summarization is actually better because it covers all bases. But just to clarify, if I interpret your response correctly it can be regarded as an adverbial form if it can be replaced by certainly or surely.

Comment: @tangosquared For sure.

Comment: So also implies that when used as an interjection (and in your last comment), it is also adverbial.

Comment: @tangosquared Yeah right! Interjections are their own thing.